# JS closure weirdness

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I am trying to set a property of a object from a function:

```
function createObject(){
    var self={};
    self.foo=function(){
        this.wheatly="apple";
    }
    return self;
}
```

The problem is that when I call self.foo(), 'this' refers to the function object (self.foo), not the parent (self). How can I force the function to set the property of the parent? There have been many similar questions on stackoverflow, but the authors keep on using this 'closure' thing, which should apply here???

Edit:

I forgot to mention that the function is called asynchronously, so here is a better example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Pj59q/
What confuses me is that the console (in chrome) is saying that `this` is an XMLHttpRequest (presumably the one declared in `self.ajax`). Is the `this` keyword just referring to whatever object called the function?

Comment: How are you calling the function? Show us all your code.

Comment: Please do not provide your question as a fiddle. Put the code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function createObject(){
    var self={};
    self.foo=function(){
        self.wheatly="apple";
    }
    return self;
}
```

What about the above?

Answer (score 1):

```
x = createObject()
>> Object {foo: function}

x.foo()
x
>> Object {foo: function, wheatly: "apple"}
```

So, what is the problem? This is the expected behavior. BTW, this has nothing to do with closures.

## Update

So it turns out you did not provide all the necessary information. You need to bind the callback you're passing to the ajax call, so it knows what `this` is supposed to be:

```
r.onload=this.foo.bind(this);
```

As a side note, the way you've structured `createObject` is a bit odd. More idiomatic would be:

```
function createObject(){
    return {
        foo: function() {
            this.wheatly="apple";
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `this` does not refer to `self.foo`, it refers to `self`. How did you arrive at the conclusion that it refers to `self.foo`? You can verify in a console that the following happens:

```
var bar = createObject();
bar.wheatly;              //=> undefined
bar.foo();
bar.wheatly;              //=> 'apple'
```

Therefore, `self` (here identified as `bar`) was correctly referenced and modified.

By the way, "closure" is the name given to the concept that when a function is created in an environment that has variables in scope, the function absorbs ("closes") those variables and continues to be able to reference them even when they go out of scope. For example:

```
var outerFunc = function() {
    var closeMe = 'hello';
    return function() {
        return closeMe;
    };
};

innerFunc = outerFunc();
innerFunc();             //=> 'hello'
```

The variable `closeMe` was correctly read and returned even though it was out of scope. This is because `innerFunc` closed it when it was defined.

I don't believe your issue (which you will have to clarify for me, please) has to do with closures.

## Edit:

Just to make sure it's clear to everyone why [TGH's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23861983/1042595) works, observe the code in the fiddle:

```
self.foo=function(){
    this.wheatly="apple";
    console.log(this);
}
self.ajax=function(){
    var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
    r.open("GET","example.com",true);
    r.onload=this.foo;
    r.send();
}
```

In this code, there are references `self.foo`, `this.foo`, and `r.onload`. These references may have different names, but they are in fact references to the *same function*. However, when the AJAX call finishes, it calls this function as `r.onload`, that is, a member of `r`. Hence, `this` points to `r` in classic object-oriented fashion.

In  [TGH's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23861983/1042595), the ever-shifting reference `this` is not used, and is instead replaced by the unambiguous reference `self` which always refers to the parent object and never to `r`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that when XMLHTTPRequest call-back the onload function, it switchs the context (this).

In other words, the XMLHTTPRequest object is implemented as :

```
function send() {
   if (status == 200) {
       this.onload();        //// Now the context is XMLHTTPRequest Object!!!!
   }
}
```

You can change you code to

```
self.ajax=function(){
    var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
    r.open("GET","/",true);
    var that = this;
    r.onload=function() {
        that.foo.apply(that);
    }
    r.send();
}
```

to bind a context, and calls the foo() with that context.